# unable to instantiate activity: android

Tags: instantiationexception

> can anyone tell me what is going on, i keep getting this error.
>   returns
>   (349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{uk.ac.surrey.ms00367/uk.ac.surrey.ms00367.Panel}: java.lang.InstantiationException: uk.ac.surrey.ms00367.Panel
>   returns

Answer (score 0):

This is thrown when a program attempts to access a constructor which is not accessible from the location where the reference is made.